# ASP.NET Forms Authentication - Multiple Logins

Tags: asp.net-membership, asp.net-authentication, asp.net-authorization

I'm sure variations of this question have been asked many times before, but I can't quite find the answer.

I have a website that is an online shop. We have the following login/account management requirements:

Members of the Admin role to login to /Admin
Members of the Pro role to login to /Pro
Members of the Customer role do not have a specific area they login to, but at the checkout we want them to be able to login so they don't have to fill in their delivery details again.

Therefore we would like the url structure to be something like:

/Checkout.aspx (/login form)
/Admin/Login.aspx
/Pro/Login.aspx (the only slight exception here is that we do want the users to be able to access the /Pro/Register.aspx page without being logged in - for obvious reasons)

I read this was possible if I remove the authentication configuration from the main web.config and created a web.config file in each of the pro and admin folders. In IIS 7 I changed the folders to applications, but then the pages couldn't access the masterpages from the main site.

Am I going about it in the right way?

Thanks in advance.

Al

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you'd need to change the folders to applications, but your strategy of creating 'sub' web.config files in each child directory is one correct way of achieving this.

The other way is to declare permissions in the root web.config for each page or directory as in the example below (from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316871)):

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms" >
            <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPNETAUTH" protection="None" path="/" timeout="20" >
            </forms>
        </authentication>
<!-- This section denies access to all files in this application except for those that you have not explicitly specified by using another setting. -->
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?" /> 
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access to the Default1.aspx page only. It is located in the same folder as this configuration file. -->
        <location path="default1.aspx">
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
        </location>
<!-- This section gives the unauthenticated user access to all of the files that are stored in the Subdir1 folder.  -->
        <location path="subdir1">
        <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users ="*" />
        </authorization>
        </system.web>
        </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hi Widor, thanks for your answer. I'm not sure though how that example would tell ASP.NET that someone accessing /Pro/SecuredPage.aspx should be redirect to /Pro/Login.aspx, or indeed the fact that only members of the Professional role should be able to login at /Pro/Login.aspx - am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I see what you want now, but until someone logs in how will you know which role they belong to?! Perhaps you want to look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin.aspx and handle the page-specific login in code-behind instead?

Comment: Hi Widor - this is very true, but if for example a standard customer logs in to the /Pro/ section it is perfectly acceptable to display a message saying they do not have access to this directory.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a new Application; just include a web.config for your sub-folder(s) with authorization allowing only the roles you want to be able to access the folder.

Comment: Hi Andy - that's what I thought, but when I put the web.config in the sub-folder I get an error message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: Ah. Correct; you'll want to trim out basically everything but the authorization elements:
<configuration>
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
   <allow roles="Admin" /> <!-- Or Pro -->
   </authorization>
 </system.web>
</configuration>